# Ajuda com WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com uma dificuldade na hora de exibir no Form. Eu tenho um Form principal (fmrPrincipal) e outro Form para cadastro de um cliente (fmrCadastraCliente). Dentro do fmrPrincipal tem um menu com o campo "Cliente" e em seguida o usuário seleciona "Cadastrar cliente".No momento que ele clicar nesta opção, quero que fique como a foto abaixo:[image: Como eu queria que ficasse]

Está imagem eu fiz no Paint, porque não consegui fazer dentro do Visual Studio. Como eu deixaria ele assim ? Estou pesquisando em alguns fóruns mas até agora nada. Tem outra maneira além dessa que estou pensando ?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você tá falando sobre a posição dos controls? Textboxes e Buttons?

Comment: Você quer que os controles do form Principal deem lugar para os controles do form de cadastro?

Comment: Alguma solução Victor ?

Answer (score 0):

No `FormPrincipal` defina a propriedade `IsMDIContainer` como true, e na hora de abrir o `FormCadastraCliente` coloque a propriedade `MdiParent` como seu form atual ('this').

Ex:

```
frmCadastraCliente form = new frmCadastraCliente();
form.MdiParent = this;
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
form.Show();
```

Answer (score -1):

> Faça isso no clique do seu botão Cadastrar cliente.

```
Form entrar = new frmMenuPrincipal();
 entrar.Show();
```

Só troque os frm pelo seu, isso é um exemplo do meu código.

frmMenuPrincipal(); é o form que você criou do cadastro.

Esse " entrar ", você pode mudar para qualquer coisa, é uma variável.